# How to align components side by side in tailwind

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

Hello I need to create an interface with tailwind css and vue. I have a filter container and a search bar which should be in different files but should show side by side. I have written the code below and at app.vue I have added a div only for search bar and filter container but still they don't show side by side. Filters are higher and search bar is below filters.
App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="bg-gray-200 font-sans flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <AppHeader />
          <div class="container w-full flex flex-wrap mx-auto px-2 pt-8 lg:pt-16 mt-16">
    <FilterContainer/>
    <SearchBar/>
    </div>
    <router-view class="flex-grow"></router-view>
    <AppFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import AppHeader from './components/layout/AppHeader';
import FilterContainer from './components/search/FilterContainer';
import SearchBar from './components/search/SearchBar';
import AppFooter from './components/layout/AppFooter';


export default {
  name: 'app',
  watch: {
      '$route' (to) {
        document.title = to.meta.title || 'Logzor'
      }
    },
  components: {
    AppHeader,
    FilterContainer,
    SearchBar,
    AppFooter
  }

}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

SearchBar.vue

```
<template>
<!-- Searchbar -->

    <div class="w-full lg:w-4/5 p-8 mt-6 lg:mt-0 text-gray-900 leading-normal bg-white border border-gray-400 border-rounded">
      <input  type="text" v-model="search.search" class="h-16 appearance-none rounded-l w-full py-2 px-2 ml-2 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none text-2xl" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
      <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-4 px-12 rounded-r ">    SEARCH   </button>
     </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'search',
  ],
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      this.$emit('collectSearch', this.search)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

FilterContainer.vue

```
<template>

         <div class="w-full lg:w-1/5 lg:px-6 text-xl text-gray-800 leading-normal">
            <p class="text-base font-bold py-2 lg:pb-6 text-gray-700">Filters</p>
            <div class="block lg:hidden sticky inset-0">
               <button id="menu-toggle" class="flex w-full justify-end px-3 py-3 bg-white lg:bg-transparent border rounded border-gray-600 hover:border-purple-500 appearance-none focus:outline-none">
                  <svg class="fill-current h-3 float-right" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                     <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"/>
                  </svg>
               </button>
            </div>

         </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Hi Malvina, can you please post the picture of how does your page look alike, because from what I'm seeing, they should be side by side on bigger screens.

Comment: @Ben This is the link to the image https://ibb.co/Fq5cmZx . I know it may seem as they are side by side but they are not. When you add elements in filter container the search bar just goes lower

Comment: Please see the answer below and let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Malvina,

I'm not sure what size of the screen you are using but from what you've posted up there, they should be displaying side by side on `lg` screens. All the other screens, they will be displaying one beneath the other.

This is happening because you have `w-full` on them and `lg:w-4/5` and `lg:w-1/5`.

All smaller screens than `lg` screen will be using `w-full` and only `lg` screens will be using `w-1/5`.

Try with `md:` instead of `lg:`. So it would be `md:w-4/5` and `md:w-1/5`.

[image: Example 1]

I hope this helps.

Here is the playground where you can try on different screen sizes, different settings.

https://tailwind.run/new

Comment: Hey @Ben I tried this one but it still doesn't work. I think the problem might be that the search bar and filter container are not on the same container as I am not sure that the container I've added at app.vue works, but I dont know how to fix it. If I put the search bar and filter container in the same file as part of the big container it works but separate no.

Comment: You can inspect the HTML using inspect tool in your browser and see if that `container` works. 

Please see that and get back to me with the findings.

Comment: https://ibb.co/M675Pqt The line I selected I believe is the problem. I could not provide a screenshot to show the div but it is as wide as the screen that's why it is under the filter container. flex-grow is used at app.vue . I tried to change it to flex-none and the search bar disappeared

Comment: Fixed it! All I had to do is to include  <router-view class="flex-grow"></router-view> inside the container. Thank you for your help